# UART receiving random values

Tags: verilog, uart, serial, quartus

I tried to transmit "S" using De0 nano FPGA board and UART over USB module . The problem is i am not receiving "s" constantly . I am using the software Called Hterm to see receiving data.

When i remove the USB to UART module from the PC and reconnect the receiving value changes.

[image]

1. After removing the Module and plug it again the value changes.
   [image]
2. And after this is received "S"
   [image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Verilog, but can you reduce your sending interval... lets say to 1 Hz?

Comment: @jsotola i checked the binary value of that , Both were matched .

Comment: @po.pe But that should be consider as solving this error right. I need 115200 baud rate

Comment: The baud rate has nothing to do with the repetition rate... for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is sending constant data stream without any pauses between symbols.

The ASCII symbol 'S' has a value of 0x53, so it is sent over the wire as repeating pattern of 0110010101 which includes the start and stop bits.

Because there is no pauses between transmissions, the receiving UART does not know which bits are the start and stop bits in the constant data stream, so it may synchronize to any wrong but valid-looking point in the stream.

There are 4 combinations of valid symbols when sending out ASCII letter 'S' constantly. In addition to the 'S', they are the following:

0101011001 is one combination that also looks like perfectly valid symbol, that's 0x35, the ASCII symbol '5' you are seeing.

0101100101 is another one, that is 0x4D, the ASCII symbol 'M'.

0010101011 is another one, that is 0xAA, which is an unprintable ASCII character, the box you are seeing.

This is why there should never be a constant symbol transmission, at least occasionally an idle space that is longer than one symbol should be sent to make the receiving UART to synchronize properly on the actual start bit.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.  A UART that's designed correctly will sample the middle of the bit period.  Once the middle of the stop bit is sampled the oversample/baud counters and state machine can be reset/initialized.  This allows a time period between the middle of the stop bit and the beginning of the start bit that allows for resynchronization.  At the start bit's edge transiton the oversample/baud counters and state machine begin their normal routines.  Also, to the OP, don't forget to double or triple register the receive line for metastability.

Comment: After reading the proposed answer again, I really don't understand what you're talking about regarding the synchronization patterns and different data.  The UART transmission data is framed by a start and stop pulse.  If the receiver doesn't see the correct logic state of the stop pulse then there is a framing error and the data is junk.

Comment: @mrbean how exactly do you tell the difference between a start/stop bit and data bits if you are constantly sending characters? Justme provides clear examples of why this is happening. You are confusing this with an intra-bit timing issue, which it is not

Comment: The start and stop bits are opposite logic states.  The transmission data is framed between those bits.  At the start of the start bit the receiver will see a falling edge.

Comment: @mrbean you are not understanding the issue. What is a start pulse? How is it special and different from any other line state? The answer is that it's not, its just the first pulse. The problem comes when you cant actually tell what is the "first pulse", because the line is a constant stream of pulses. In that case, you have to rely on framing errors to tell you what is and isn't an actual start pulse, and in this case, thats not enough

Comment: After idle, the receiver sees a falling edge of the receive line.  That edge kicks off the baud counter and state machine.  The receive line is oversampled and the middle of the start bit (low) is sampled.  A bit counter counts the data bits. Once that's done, the middle of the stop bit is sampled and everything is reset right after.  Ready for the falling edge of the next start bit.  Explain how you see things.  Obviously the line needs to be idle in the beginning. The receiver can't just jump into the middle of a bit stream.

Comment: @mrbean the point here is that there is no idle, so the receiver cant distinguish whats happening. It absolutely is jumping into the middle of a bitstream

Comment: You need an idle between a large stream of data.  You can't just jump into the middle of the data randomly.  Sounds like someone is doing something stupid.  I mean there are ways to slip bits and what not given a fixed framing pattern.

Comment: @mrbean that's literally what the answer is saying. "This is why there should never be a constant symbol transmission, at least occasionally an idle space that is longer than one symbol should be sent to make the receiving UART to synchronize properly on the actual start bit."

Comment: I must have missed that part.  I didn't fully understand the OP's setup.  It's written poorly.  I get it now.

Comment: @mrbean this has nothing to do with sampling at the middle of a bit period to synchronize to middle of a bit. It's about synchronizing to constant data stream when suddenly connecting wires during transmission, from which the receiver cannot know which bits are framing and which are data.

Comment: Yup I got it now.  I wasn't clear on what the OP was doing.  Makes sense.

Comment: @Justme thanks for your answer , as far as i understand from your reply i have to add a delay at the IDEAL state so that Uart synchronize properly on the actual start bit right?

Comment: Yes add a delay in the idle state. Make it 1 millisecond or something.  You can shorten it up later on.

Comment: @Justme I have added the delay but this doesn't solve the issue i am receiving the box character again

Comment: Actually, you should only start your transmitter after the receiver is connected and reset. Make sure the receiver is reset and ready for data first before you hook up and start the transmitter.  You may need to close out of the terminal and start it back up with the transmitter (FPGA) disconnected.

Comment: How long a delay? It must be more than 9 bits, and if you have say 10 bits and that is 2170 clocks of 25 MHz; it does not fit into 8-bit counter.

Comment: I think hooking up a receiver in the middle of a continuous serial stream is asking for trouble.  Whether there is an idle period or not it's bad practice.  The receiver should be up and ready to receive data before the transmitter begins transmitting anything.  Not doing so will cause issues.  Also, the OP removed the Verilog code.  There's no way to tell what his code/setup is actually doing.  Why is he disconnecting and reconnecting the receiver when the transmitter is constantly transmitting data?  Idle or not that's going to cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to Justmes answer (feel free to combine this into your answer):

This is a UART Transmission of an S:
[image]

This is what happens if you dont have an idle:

[image]

And this part is what the receiver sees as a repeating 0xAA:
[image]

edit: to be clear, i dont think this should be marked as the answer. This should just be an addendum to Justme's answer

Comment: @BeB00 I Tried to add the delay but this doesn't work i am receiving the Box character again and i edited the code above.

Comment: @UnparedElectron the proper way to debug this is with an oscilloscope. I dont see your code in your question anymore